# Get Response, Url and Url code in Textview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I am trying to make a post request to a url and get the URL, Response Code and Response displayed in a `TextView`. I am able to get the URL and Response Code in the Logs but Unable to get the response.
Please check the code and tell how to get all the three printed in a `TextView`
Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String rescode,urlcode,responsecode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String url = "http://google.com";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                    .openConnection();



            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    con.getOutputStream());

            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /*TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            urlcode = url.getBytes().toString();
            rescode = responsecode.getBytes().toString();

            tv2.getText().toString();
            tv2.setText("URL-  "+urlcode);
            tv3.setText("ResponseCode-  "+rescode);*/

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : -----------------------" + url);
    //      System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : -------------------------------" + responseCode);


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println("+++++++++"+response.toString());
        //  System.out.println("Response" +response);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            rescode = response.toString();

            tv.setText("aa"+rescode);
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("MainActivity.LongOperation.doInBackground()"+e);

        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
}
```

Log

```
05-09 16:09:59.642: I/System.out(16309): Sending 'POST' request to URL : ---------------http://google.com

05-09 16:09:59.652: I/System.out(16309): Response Code : ------------------------------405

    050916:09:59.652:I/System.out(16309):MainActivity.LongOperation.doInBackground()java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://google.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't access UI from `doInBackground` method

Try The following

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String url = "http://google.com";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                .openConnection();



        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                con.getOutputStream());

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /*TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        urlcode = url.getBytes().toString();
        rescode = responsecode.getBytes().toString();

        tv2.getText().toString();
        tv2.setText("URL-  "+urlcode);
        tv3.setText("ResponseCode-  "+rescode);*/

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : -----------------------" + url);
//      System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : -------------------------------" + responseCode);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
       if(in!=null){
           while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
          }
        in.close();
       }

        // print result
        System.out.println("+++++++++"+response.toString());
    //  System.out.println("Response" +response);

        rescode = response.toString();


        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out
                .println("MainActivity.LongOperation.doInBackground()"+e);

    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    tv.setText("aa"+result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
}
}
}
```

Comment: is this line printing  something    System.out.println("+++++++++"+response.toString());

Comment: then there is problem in BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

Comment: I have added the log please check

Comment: can you tell what to change?

Comment: I have seen your log cat , http://google.com  try to change link as it does not return anything in the respose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77380/discussion-between-nilesh-and-karma5).